# Form control missing randomly for reactive form with filter pipe

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-pipe

Below is a simple reactive form with the filter of an array of checkboxes.
As soon as page render getting error

> ```
> Cannot find control with path: 'accountsArray -> 555'
> ```

However, the filter is working perfectly, but while removing any character from filter throws an error

> ```
> Cannot find control with path: 'accountsArray -> 123'
> ```

Form control not found based on search.

Below is length code, but that will help you to understand clearly.

**Component:**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormArray, FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { SubAccount } from './account-model';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  searchForm: FormGroup;
  searchTerm = '';
  formUpdated = false;

  accounts = [
    new SubAccount('123'),
    new SubAccount('555'),
    new SubAccount('123555')
  ];
  subAccount = [];



  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  get accountsArray(): FormArray {
    return this.searchForm.get('accountsArray') as FormArray;
  }

  addAccount(theAccount: SubAccount) {
    this.accountsArray.push(this.fb.group({
      account: theAccount
    }));
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.formUpdated = false;
    this.searchForm = this.fb.group({
      accountSearch: '',
      accountsArray: this.fb.array([new FormControl('')])
    });

    this.accounts.forEach((field: any) => {
      this.subAccount.push({ key: field.key, value: field.key });
    });

    const fieldFGs = this.subAccount.map((field) => {
      const obj = {};
      if (field.value) {
        obj[field.value] = true;
      } else {
        obj[field] = true;
      }
      return this.fb.group(obj);
    });
    const fa = this.fb.array(fieldFGs);
    this.searchForm.setControl('accountsArray', fa);
    this.formUpdated = true;
  }

  getAccountNumber(account: SubAccount) {
    return Object.keys(account)[0];
  }
}
```

**View:**

```html
<div [formGroup]="searchForm" *ngIf="formUpdated">
 <label for="search">Find an account...</label>
  <input id="search" formControlName="accountSearch" [(ngModel)]="searchTerm" />
 <div formArrayName="accountsArray" *ngIf="formUpdated">
  <div *ngFor="let account of accountsArray.controls | filter: 'key' :searchTerm; let ind=index">
      <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_claim_debtor_{{ind}}" formControlName="{{getAccountNumber(account.controls)}}"/>
        <span> {{getAccountNumber(account.controls)}} </span>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

**Pipe:**

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'filter'
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(items: any[], field: string, value: string): any[] {
    if (!value && !items) {
      return items;
    }
    return items.filter((item) => {
      const val = Object.keys(item.controls)[0];
      if (val && val.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) >= 0) {
        return true
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Appreciate your help.

---

**Stackblitz link:**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9ouyqr

Comment: Try this:https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-search-filter

Comment: This is kind of simple array, I have an array with form control that causes errors. Without form control, I am successfully able to create a filter.

Comment: @HardikShah [you should not use filtering pipes](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe).

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9ouyqr link, can you help me out there?

Comment: @trichetriche using the same. but filter pipe with an array of form control is the issue.

Comment: That do'snt change the fact that you should not use filtering pipes.

Comment: Aah, misunderstood your last comment, lemme look into the documents, the link you have provided.

Comment: @trichetriche, Hope you understand the requirement. As filtering pipe is not a good idea, any suggestion to follow?

Comment: This is explained in the link that you seem to have not opened.

Comment: @trichetriche, I have opened and tried those example to fit my requirement. But bad luck. Anyways, I am trying to resolve those errors that I am getting after applying those examples. Thank you.

Comment: @HardikShah I have seen your sandbox and there seems to be no error.

Comment: @trichetriche, have you tried to filter? Try a search, deb_1 and then just remove 1 from search so dev_ will be the string and you will get an error for formControl not found.

Comment: @HardikShah I see, I tried to filter, but not on wrong values. Well for starters you have a terrible design in this sandbox. And it seems to come from that : now you expose a [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info) and expect your bad design to work. You should instead explain what you have , what your trying to achieve, and what issues you encounter.

Comment: So far I have added code, is the same I have in my project, due to legality issue I can not share actual whole code, So have pasted same code but with dummy data. The actual problem is, I have already checkbox list with some person name, implemented as form control. Now I need to add filter box on top of them, as person list may greater 100-200. And by filtering you can select that person by clicking on checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

please check the **[formGroupName]="ind"** , it is not written while iterating the form array ,formGroupname should be addeed with the form index

```
<div [formGroup]="searchForm" *ngIf="formUpdated">
    <label for="search">Find an account...</label>
  <input id="search" formControlName="accountSearch" [(ngModel)]="searchTerm" />
    <div formArrayName="accountsArray" *ngIf="formUpdated">
        <div [formGroupName]="ind" *ngFor="let account of accountsArray.controls | filter: 'key' :searchTerm; let ind=index"
    >
      <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_claim_debtor_{{ind}}" formControlName="{{getAccountNumber(account.controls)}}"/>
        <span> {{getAccountNumber(account.controls)}} </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Still, the issue persists, can you look into https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9ouyqr ?

Comment: Try a search, `deb_1` and then just remove `1` from search so `dev_` will be the string and you will get an error for formControl not found.